# Cauchy-Lipschitz application

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

This is my exercise :

> Consider the differential equation $y''(t)+a(t)y'(t)+b(t)y(t)=0$ where $a,b$ are continuous functions on an interval $I$. Show that the zeros of a non-zero solution are at most countable.

---

**What I have done :** we can transform the equation in
$$X'(t)=A(t)X(t)=:F(t,X(t))$$ with $X=\begin{pmatrix}y\\y'\end{pmatrix}$,  $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-b&-a\end{pmatrix}$ and $F:I\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2.$ Then, $t$ being fixed, we have
$$||F(t,Y)-F(t,X)||=||A(Y-X)||\leq|||A(t)|||\times||Y-X||$$
which shows that $F$ is Lipschitz - and so local-Lipschitz - about its second variable. Then we can apply Cauchy-Lipschitz's theorem which gives existence and unicity of a solution given initials conditions.

Now assume it exists a non-zero solution $y$ with a no-countable set of zeros $Z=y^{-1}(\{0\})$. Then it exists a limit point $x_*$ in this set, and let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of elements of $Z\backslash\{x_*\}$ such as $x_n\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} x_*.$ By continuity of $y$ we get $y(x_*)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y(x_n)=0$. We also get that $y'(x_*)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{y(x_n)-y(x_*)}{x_n-x_*}=0$, and now we can apply the Cauchy-Lipschitz's theorem which give us $y\equiv0$, and get a contradiction.

---

**My questions are :**

Is this proof correct, and if yes, how can I strictly prove that a non-countable set of $\mathbb{R}$ has at least a limit point ? Thank you for yours answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to just reformulate the assertion: Every set of isolated point in $\Bbb R$ is at most countable. Since it can be covered by disjoint open intervals, and each interval contains at least one rational number.

---

The remainder of the argument is ok. -- Where is the boundary between versions of the theorem labeled Picard-Lindelöf and Cauchy-Lipschitz? I only know that the one with the global Lipschitz condition belongs to the first, the one with continuously differentiability to the second.

Comment: Indeed it helps ! I don't know about differences between Picard-Lindelöf and Cauchy-Lipschitz, because in France all the results about existence-unicity etc. are gathered as Cauchy results (biggest ones being Cauchy-Peano and Cauchy-Lipschitz). Thank you for the answer !